# efficient way to do multi threaded calls to sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

i have an sql stored procedure that will call to TOP 1000 records from a table that function like a queue-in this table there will be more or less 30,000-40,000 records.the call to the SP takes ~4 seconds (there's an xml column) so to finish the calls it will take ~2 minutes.
i thought to use multi threaded calls and to insert the records to a sync dictionary\list.
did someone did that before? any efficient way to end the calls as soon as possible?
Thanks...

Comment: Consider optimizing the query before resorting to threads.

Comment: @John - I'd vote that up if you posted it as an answer - some of the best advice around.

Comment: @Donnie: done, with some elaboration.

Comment: Do you plan to fetch or to insert from multiple threads, I can't figure it out from your question...

Comment: i have optimize the query with the help of a DBA. he says that due to the use of a column with the type of xml, he can't optimize it anymore than ~4 seconds. i'm planning to fetch from the table until a record that is marked as the last record.

Comment: FYI, I have not found XML columns to be that slow in general.

Answer (score 6):

Consider optimizing the query before resorting to threads.

In my experience, when beginners at multi-threading implement threads, it usually does not improve performance. Worse, it usually introduces subtle errors which can be difficult to debug.

Optimize the query first, and you may find that you don't need threads.

Even if you implemented them, eventually you'll have SQL Server doing too much work, and the threaded requests will simply have to wait.

Comment: Please notice that the query is after optimaztion of indexes and more by a DBA.

Answer (score 3):

Basic mistake is wanting to insert into the database from multiple threads and overload server with connections, locks, and eventually bring it to its knees.

If you are READING the data, you will do much better if you find a query that will perform faster and fetch as much data as you can at once.

To me, it seems like your problem is not solvable on its level - maybe if you elaborate what you want to do you'll get better advice.

EDIT:

I did use SQL as a queue once - and I just remembered - to dequeue, you'll have to use result from the first query to get input to the second, so threads are out of the question.  Or, you'll have to MARK your queued data 'done' in the database, and your READ will become UPDATE -> resulting to locking.

If you are reading, and you want to react as soon as possible, you can use DataReader, then read ALL of the data, and chunk your processing into threads - read 100 records, fork a thread and pass it to it... then next records and so on.  That way you'll be able to balance your resource usage.

Comment: i'll elaborate a little more.I have a table that gets records. each set of ~40,000 marked with a GUID. i want to take the 40,000 records in sections of 1,000 records (the SELECT of this recors takes ~4 seconds to high IO becuase of xml column) to a windows service and do some work. the get of the records must be as fast as possible.

Comment: So how do you plan to fetch NEXT 1000 records while first query is running?

Comment: OK, I saw your other answer - anyway, I would go with reading all records and dispatching work upon reading a row (or several rows) through the DataReader.  If your query has nothing special, first row will be ready extremely quickly, and you'll have every row as fast as your IO will permit.

Comment: Your query shouldn't last 4 seconds no mater what.  Measure query running time to the first record, and measure what it takes to fetch all of the records.

Comment: but won't the call to the ExecuteReader will take also 4 seconds?i will try using DataReader and measure the results.I've read that selecting a table that holds a xml column is slow so i took the DBA word that this query cannot be improved.

Comment: ExecuteReader can't take more then few milliseconds if you aren't sorting and aren't filtering. Either your table design or query should be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the data asynchronously using DataReader; fetch the columns that can uniquely identify the row in the database .Populate the Queue to hold the returned data value (Custom Object) and run work threads to perform the task against the queue.

You have to decide ***how many worker threads should be implemented***  to perform the task as threads have their own overheads and if not implemented correctly could be a nightmare.

Comment: do you have any sample for worker threads implementation for such kind of a job?the problem is that the DB queue can be empty until a proccess start so i don't want to activate uneccesary multi threding.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if you're selecting the 1000 most recently added rows, or the 1000 rows with the highest value in a particular column, nor is it clear whether your rows are mutable -- i.e. a row might qualify for the top 1000 yesterday but then get updated so that it no longer qualifies today.  But if the individual rows are not mutable, you could have a separate table for the TOP1000, and when the 1001st row is inserted into it, an after-insert trigger would move the 1001st row (however you determine that row) to a HISTORY table.  That would make the selection virtually instantaneous: select * from TOP1000. You'd simply combine the two tables with a UNION when you need to query the TOP1000 and HISTORY as though they were one table. Or instead of trigger you could wrap the insert and 1001st-row delete in a transaction.

Different can of worms, though, if the rows mutate, and can move in and out of the top 1000.

Comment: Hi,i'm updating the status of TOP 1000 records (RecordID) and insert them to a temp table from which i'm doing the select.

Comment: So, you are doing an update of 1000 rows in the base table, then selecting those 1000 rows once again to insert them into a temp table, and then you do a select * from temptable?  BTW, it is not considered best practice to rely upon the primary key for anything other than uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to you can start BGWorkers that individually make connections to the server and report back with their progress.

I did the same thing for an elaborate export/import application to move roughly 50GB of data (4GB deflatestream'ed) except I only used the BGWorker to do the work consecutively, not concurrently, without locking up the UI-thread..

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct BillingData
{
    public int CustomerTrackID, CustomerID;
    public DateTime BillingDate;
}

public Queue<BillingData> customerQueue = new Queue<BillingData>();
volatile static int ThreadProcessCount = 0;
readonly static object threadprocesslock = new object();
readonly static object queuelock = new object();
readonly static object countlock = new object();
AsyncCallback asyncCallback

// Pulling the Data Aync from the Database
private void StartProcess()
{
  SqlCommand command = SQLHelper.GetCommand("GetRecordsByBillingTrackID");
  command.Connection = SQLHelper.GetConnection("Con");SQLHelper.DeriveParameters(command);
  command.Parameters["@TrackID"].Value = trackid;
  asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(FetchData);
  command.BeginExecuteXmlReader(asyncCallback, command);
}

public void FetchData(IAsyncResult c1)
    {
        SqlCommand comm1 = (SqlCommand)c1.AsyncState;
        System.Xml.XmlReader xr = comm1.EndExecuteXmlReader(c1);
        xr.Read();
        string data = "";
        while (!xr.EOF)
        {
        data = xr.ReadOuterXml();
        XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
        dom.LoadXml("<data>" + data + "</data>");
        BillingData billingData;
        billingData.CustomerTrackID = Convert.ToInt32(dom.FirstChild.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["CustomerTrackID"].Value);
        billingData.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dom.FirstChild.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["CustomerID"].Value);
        billingData.BillingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dom.FirstChild.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["BillingDate"].Value);
lock (queuelock)
{
   if (!customerQueue.Contains(billingData))
   {
     customerQueue.Enqueue(billingData);
   }
}
   AssignThreadProcessToTheCustomer();


}



xr.Close();



}



// Assign the Threads based on the data pulled
private void AssignThreadProcessToTheCustomer()
{
int TotalProcessThreads =  5;
int TotalCustomersPerThread = 5;
if (ThreadProcessCount < TotalProcessThreads)
{
int ThreadsNeeded = (customerQueue.Count % TotalCustomersPerThread == 0) ?    (customerQueue.Count / TotalCustomersPerThread) : (customerQueue.Count / TotalCustomersPerThread + 1);
int count = 0;
 if (ThreadsNeeded > ThreadProcessCount)
{
 count = ThreadsNeeded - ThreadProcessCount;
 if ((count + ThreadProcessCount) > TotalProcessThreads)
    count = TotalProcessThreads - ThreadProcessCount;
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
ThreadProcess objThreadProcess = new ThreadProcess(this);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(objThreadProcess.BillingEngineThreadPoolCallBack, count);
lock (threadprocesslock)
{
 ThreadProcessCount++;
}
}

public void BillingEngineThreadPoolCallBack(object threadContext)
{
BillingData? billingData = null;
while (true)
{
   lock (queuelock)
   {
      billingData = ProcessCustomerQueue();
   }
 if (billingData != null)
{
 StartBilling(billingData.Value);
}
else
 break;

More....
}
```